# Filter array of objects into new arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

In React I have:

```
    state = {
     Producers: [], 
     France: [],
     Spain: [],
     Germany: [],
     Portugal: [],
     Greece: [],
     Austria: [],
     isLoading: false
     };
```

Producers Array:

```
     {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0bf1815cc7a2225edab0b"),
    "Code" : "FPG-BCH14",
    "URL" : "/jSQcl",
    "Just_In" : "",
    "Country" : "France",
    "Region" : "Burgundy"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0bf1815cc7a2225edab0c"),
    "Code" : "FPG-CHA17",
    "URL" : "/XPxx",
    "Just_In" : "",
    "Country" : "France",
    "Region" : "Burgundy"  
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0bf1815cc7a2225edab0d"),
    "Code" : "FPG-BPN16",
    "Just_In" : "",
    "Country" : "France",
    "Region" : "Burgundy"

},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0bf1815cc7a2225edab0e"),
    "Code" : "PAP-VIN17",
    "Country" : "Portugal",
    "Region" : "Vinho Verde",
    "Subregion" : "Lima"

}
```

Right now I have all objects in `state.Producers` and I want to put any object that has the value `state.Producers.Country === "France"` (and so on for all the countries).

This is how I'm setting state:

```
    loadProducers = () => {

     API.getProducers()
     .then(res => 
     this.setState({Producers: res.data})
     )
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
       }
```

so I was thinking I need another `.then` statement after setting state for producers and then `.filter` for each country, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you post an example of how your data structure was set? (the `res.data` object)

Comment: Please clarify your question more like what do you want to achieve in the end and how do you want to compare?

Comment: Usually it's best to not duplicate state like this. If `Producers` already has all your data just filter it before rendering:
`const france = state.producers.filter(p => p.Country === "France")`

Comment: Thanks @RobertMennell @BrunoMonteiro, I'm working on understanding this further... I've edited my question above to include a sample of what is in `state.Producers` array. Many thanks for all input!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you `res.data` has a structure of `[{Country: string}, {Country: string}...]`, you could create a `updatedState` object and push the items into it.

Something like this:

```
const loadProducers = () => {
    API.getProducers()
    .then(res => {
        const updatedState = {
            Producers: [], 
            France: [],
            Spain: [],
            Germany: [],
            Portugal: [],
            Greece: [],
            Austria: []
        };
        res.data.forEach((item) => {
            updatedState[item.Country].push(item);
        })
        // This line if you also need everything inside Producers
        updatedState.Producers = res.data;

        this.setState(updatedState);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: This will be prone to timing problems and thus possibly unreliable

Comment: This means maintaining the fetch will also mean maintaining the derived state

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but what you mean by "maintaining the fetch will also mean maintaining the derived state"?

Comment: What happens if they change from using fetch to using a library that doesn't use .then or they decide to wrap it in a different library for a more maintainable opinionated response inspector(anything 400 goes to a different callback, 200 goes to success)? They would need to maintain more logic than just making sure the same key on an object is an array of objects with a country key to be put into state, they would always have to adapt the function

Comment: Hmm...that doesn't sound a problem with the answer though. The question was much more related to javascript and how to parse the response to multiple arrays. If the approach changes to not use promises than a refactor is needed anyway. I see your point, but don't agree with the downvote...it is the samething if I downvote your answer saying that you don't handle if they wnat to change the key from "Country" to something else...

Comment: If they clarify their question with where and how they are fetching the data(single time at mount, showing a loader otherwise, no other timing issues) I'd more than happily remove my down vote. sadly without that I need to consider all possible situations and the harm it could cause on their journey with React.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way.

```
loadProducers = () => {
 API.getProducers()
  .then(({ data }) =>
    // Here we reduce all the results with respect to the country associated with
    updatedState = data.reduce((res, obj) => {
     if (!res[obj.Country]) {
       res[obj.Country] = [];
     }
     return { ...res, [obj.Country]: [...res[obj.Country], obj] }
    }, {});

    // Push all the data into Producers provided that you need it here. else you can ignore this line :)
    updatedState.Producers = data;

    //Finally update the state 
    this.setState(updatedState);
  ).catch(({ response }) => console.log(response));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will be prone to timing problems and possible unreliable

Comment: What do you mean by timing problems? may be you should give more details than just expecting us to google when u rate down.

Comment: What happens if I make two requests, and they arrive at near the same time, but the old data arrives second, wiping out the new data due to the asynchronous nature of state updates?

Comment: I guess the question was about how to do it and not about where to do it.

Comment: @RobertMennell In case if you have multiple api's and also that different data structures being returned from each API, would you confine your state to a standard structure and not consider the type of data that is coming when you are making multiple api calls? In that case even you approach is not gonna be maintainable and would probably need to use state management library like redux.

Comment: My method merely requires that the producers enter the state of his component(or even the props of his component) in the same structure every time, REGARDLESS of whatever method is used to fetch them. The nice thing is that at the .then on the api call they can just make it look like the producers array of objects with a key of country and it will just work meaning they can integrate an endless amount of APIs and chaining transformers and have a single interface for updating the state.

Comment: How would you handle two api's returning Producers and Consumers? Two if conditions? or Merge Them? :D

Comment: Your condescension is now obvious, reported. They would merely need to do whatever in a single place to update their state based on the network requests and the top level state, meaning they would be able to adapt in a single place to any number of constructs or data sources. In. A. Single. Place. Of. Maintenance.

Answer (score -1):

`React.Component#setState()` does not return anything so a `Promise#then()` will have an undefined passed to it's callback. To avoid this, instead pass [a callback to `setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) so that it runs after the state update, [but you should use the proper method and use the life cycle `React.Component#componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#componentdidupdate). The are many reasons you should want to use the life cycle including so that you can change where your data source comes from easily without changing how the state derives itself, the life cycle will need little to no maintenance, and it will always operate when the component gets updated meaning you won't have timing issues based on racing asynchronous conditions.

```js
this.componentDidUpdate = function componentDidUpdate(
  previousProps,
  previousState
) {
  // wrap it in a comparison so that you don't infinitely loop
  if (//compare producers to previous producers here) {
    // they have changed, update state, use updater to prevent timing problems
    this.setState(state => {
      // keep changing data in sync
      // this also allows you to fetch changing data over time
      const update = {...state};
      state.producers.forEach(producer => {
        // safely initialize
        update[producer.Country] = update[producer.Country] || [];
        if (!update[producer.country].find(producer) {
          // push onto
          update[producer.Country].push(producer);
        }
      });
      return update;
    })
  }
}
```

This is guaranteed to run on a state update in a safe manner in a class, and keep your concerns(fetch) and derivatives(derived structures) separate and easy to maintain.

Comment: componentDidUpdate is a lifecycle method and you dont need to bind it.

Comment: Good catch, removing that